# Inline CSS doesn't overwrite CSS

Tags: css, antd

I am writing some sort of instruction manual. I wanted to make my text bold.

```
const styles={
  boldText: {
     fontWeight:"bold"
   }
}

.
.
.
<Input style={styles.boldText} disable="true" defaultValue="hello world!"/>
```

However, in the output, the text isn't bold. Seems like ANTD has some default CSS.

Don't inline CSS has priority?

Answer (score 1):

try to fix the code like this ..

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  boldText: {
     fontWeight:"bold"
   }
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main rule in CSS is: The more specific a styles is the more priority it has. However, your inline style is pointing to the same style you have created above so you are disabling it. In order to avoid it, just use a separated file for your styles.

Comment: sorry, my questions were a bit unclear. I have edited it.